# How to display emojis inside a sketch?

Tags: processing, emoji, processing.js

I have the following method in my draw() method:

```
PFont f = createFont("Arial",size,true);
textFont(f,size); 
text(char(symbol), x, y);
```

where symbol is the integer unicode range of the emojis  128512-128591.

but my output only displays empty blocks instead of the emoji.

What is the correct way to do this? Also, how can I display rich emojis smilar to the ones found in mobile apps etc?

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the encoding/characterset somewhere? Just a guess

Comment: If this is Processing (which is Java under the hood), then using a specific font will give you exactly the characters in that font and none else. That may be the first problem. The other is that the `char` function probably doesn't support non-BMP characters (> 65535) and you may have to do UTF-16 manually, e.g. `char(55357) + char(56842)`. If you see two boxes that's an indicator for that. As for colourful emoji: Use pictures; neither browsers nor Java are very successful at using coloured fonts so far.

Answer (score 0):

often times, I can just copy and paste an emoji into a `text(text, x, y);` function. but even though it is possible to do that emojis display differently across different platforms. So you probably would want to looks for another option.